# React redux favorites action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am new to react-redux world and having some trouble visualising a piece of complex data flow (I think).

Assume the state contains a collection of tracks and an array of favorite track ids. User could favorite a track from a number of various components e.g. musicplayer, tracklist, charts and all the others would have to rerender.

At the moment, I'm triggering an action to add/remove the track id to/from the favorites array. But I can't quite see how to proceed from there.

My plan is to trigger another action for e.g. the trackItem reducer to listen and carry on. Or could each related component directly subscribe to changes of the favorites collection? Or can I have two reducers listening to the same action? I have now idea how to implement something like that and also I have a gut feeling that I'm on the wrong path.

Feels like I'm struggling to get rid of my backbone-marionette habits. How would you do it?

My other plan is to have an isFavorited boolean within the track item json and use an action/reduces to update/toggle that property. I understand that [normalizr](https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr) will merge instances with the same id, so any component subscribed to its changes will react.

Answer (score 2):

> Or could each related component directly subscribe to changes of the
>   favorites collection

They could. But do these components all share some parent component? If so I would have that parent component subscribe to the state change of the favorites array, and pass that down as props to the components that need it.

I would recommend really reading through the redux docs: https://rackt.github.io/redux/

Especially usage with React: https://rackt.github.io/redux/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Typically you would have a 'smart' component that renders for a route, and that would subscribe to the redux store and pass down the data its nested 'dumb' components need.

So have your smart component(s) subscribe to the state change of the favorites array and pass it down as a prop to the components that need it.

Answer (score 2):

It's all right to listen to one action in more than one reducer, so maybe go down that route?

Do your components share common parent component? If they do, `connect` it to your redux app state and pass favorite ids array down to each one; then dispatch action `addFav` or `removeFav` from any component, react in `favorites` reducer and see redux passing new props to react components.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first understand about smart and dumb components in reactjs, here is the [link](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0), so you will be having a single smart which connects to you reducer and updates your child(dumb) component.

If you still wants to have two reducers, you can have a action which executes its operation as a result it calls another action. to achieve this you need to have a [redux-async-transitions](https://github.com/Cron-J/redux-async-transitions), the example code is given below

```
function action1() {
 return {
  type: types.SOMEFUNCTION,
  payload: {
   data: somedata
  },
  meta: {
   transition: () => ({
    func: () => {
     return action2;
    },
    path : '/somePath',
    query: {
     someKey: 'someQuery'
    },
    state: {
     stateObject: stateData
    }
   })
  }
 }
}
```